# Does Sensodyne Toothpaste reduce teeth sensitivity?

Tags: medical-science, dentistry

The manufacturers of [Sensodyne](http://www.sensodyne.com.au/howsensodyneworks.aspx) toothpaste claims their products "helps relieve the pain of sensitive teeth", using the active ingredients of (either) [Strontium Chloride or Potassium Nitrate](http://www.sensodyne.com.au/howsensodyneworks.aspx)

Does Sensodyne toothpaste actually reduce sensitivity in one's teeth? If so, how?

Comment: It seems to work fine. As far as I know enamel is actually porous and the the paste can penetrate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Sensodyne](http://www.sensodyne.com.au/howsensodyneworks.aspx) marketing includes an explanation, *some of which* includes a reference.

They claim that the products containing Potassium Nitrate work because the potassium stops the nerves from firing, citing *Nagata, T. et al, Clinical evaluation of a potassium nitrate dentrific for the treatment of dentinal hypersensitivity, J Clin Periodontal. 1994;21:217-221.*

They claim the products containing Strontium Chloride work by blocking the exposed tubules within the dentinal tissue, that stops fluid flow that triggers pain. They do *not* provide references on their web-site to support that claim.

Answer (score 6):

Here are a couple of sources that might be helpful:
[This study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19081901) addressed the "clinical effectiveness of strontium chloride" and found that out of a group of 132 patients, 72% had reduced discomfort and pain. No mechanism was offered.

[This study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21411060) seems to indicate that fluid flow is associated with dentinal pain (this addresses thermal stimulation)

[This study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12167939) indicates that potassium nitrate works through desensitization of nerve tissue within the tubules