# Does Sensodyne Total Care Toothpaste remove plaque, protect against tooth decay and help sensitive gums?

Tags: medical-science, consumer-products, dentistry

As shown in the toothpaste cover:

[image: Sensodyne box]

It is mentioned that using Sensodyne Total Care toothpaste can do the following:

> Protects against sensitive teeth
>
> Protects against tooth decay
>
> Removes plaque
>
> Helps maintain healthy gums
>
> 24/7 Sensitivity Protection

We have an existing question that addresses the first and last claims:
[Does Sensodyne Toothpaste reduce teeth sensitivity?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3389/does-sensodyne-toothpaste-actually-work)

Does Sensodyne remove plaque, protect against tooth decay and help sensitive gums?

Comment: The first and fifth claims look similar to the previous question.  The second, third and fourth are true (to a degree) of brushing teeth in general with any toothpaste.

Comment: Do you appeal to one's personal experience? If not, the answer probably depends on whether the real investigations were done, which likely weren't. Also, this is all about the `degree` of correspondence to reality. I'm sure that many of the statements are truthful to a certain extent (by a certain measure). Sorry for my English (just in case)

Comment: I edited this question to be more focussed on the non-duplicate parts. This question and its counterpart are a perfect example of why the title should contain the key claim.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Sensodyne Total Care toothpaste may work as mentioned on its cover based on the ingredients present such as Potassium Nitrate 5.0% w/w and Sodium Fluoride 0.306% w/w.

Per the Sensodyne Total Care F product [information](http://www.mhra.gov.uk/home/groups/spcpil/documents/spcpil/con1412919993512.pdf), the pharmacodynamic properties of Sensodyne Total Care Toothpaste are  based on "the antibacterial formulation contains potassium ions which are thought to reduce hypersensitivity by interfering with pulpal nerve conduction. With twice daily tooth brushing, Sensodyne Total Care F Toothpaste delivers the regular doses of potassium ions required to build up and then maintain its depolarising activity, thereby providing ongoing protection from, and prevention of dentinal hypersensitivity. Once regular use is discontinued, the desensitising activity of the potassium ions within the dentine tubules will slowly be lost and sensitivity pain will return."

Per study 'Desensitizing toothpaste versus placebo for dentin hypersensitivity: a systematic review and meta-analysis' by Ji-Hyun Bae et. al [2015](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/jcpe.12347/abstract) assessing the effect of desensitizing toothpaste on dentin hypersensitivity, the conclusions were

> The study reports that there is sufficient evidence to support the use of potassium-, stannous fluoride-, potassium and stannous fluoride-, calcium sodium phosphosilicate-, and arginine-containing desensitizing toothpastes for dentin hypersensitivity, but not the use of strontium-containing desensitizing toothpaste.

Sensodyne Total Care toothpaste also contains sodium fluoride which is an established anticaries agent. Fluoride Recommendations Work [Group](http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/rr5014a1.htm) states "Cariogenic bacteria (i.e., bacteria that cause dental caries) reside in dental plaque, a sticky organic matrix of bacteria, food debris, dead mucosal cells, and salivary components that adheres to tooth enamel. Plaque also contains minerals, primarily calcium and phosphorus, as well as proteins, polysaccharides, carbohydrates, and lipids. Fluoride concentrated in plaque and saliva inhibits the demineralization of sound enamel and enhances the remineralization of demineralized enamel. Fluoride also inhibits dental caries by affecting the activity of cariogenic bacteria. Adults also benefit from fluoride, rather than only children, as was previously assumed."

Per American Dental Association [ADA](http://www.ada.org/en/science-research/ada-seal-of-acceptance/product-category-information/toothpaste), "a fluoride toothpaste helps remove plaque, a film of bacteria that forms on teeth and gums every day. Plaque can cause gum disease and tooth decay. Fluoride helps prevent tooth decay by strengthening tooth enamel. All ADA-Accepted toothpastes contain fluoride".

However per systematic review of selected desensitizing OTC Products by E. Talioti et. al in [2014](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4005032/) "to determine whether there was any evidence on the clinical effectiveness of selected desensitizing toothpastes, calcium sodium phosphosilicate (CSPS), amorphous calcium phosphate (ACP), nanohydroxyapatite, and casein phosphopeptide-amorphous calcium phosphate (tooth mousse) on reducing dentine hypersensitivity (DH)" the conclusions were,

> Due to the small number of included studies, there are limited clinical data to support any claims of clinical efficacy of these OTC products. Further studies are therefore required to determine the efficacy of these products in well-controlled RCT studies with a larger sample size.

Comment: Thanks for addressing this old question and bringing it to our attention. I pulled the rug on you slightly by moving the sensitivity claim out of scope. Sorry about that, but I think you could easily take that portion out of this answer and post it as an answer on the other question, so it wasn't a waste of your time.

Comment: @Oddthinking, its good that you modified this question so that the title contains the key claim but the other question has been already answered. Thanks a lot for your efforts!!!!